# Trying to choose an image from image gallery from a Fragment - Android

Tags: android, android-activity

I am trying to pick an image from image gallery using this code from a fragment:

```
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setType("image/*");
    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Picture"), PICK_IMAGE_CALLBACK);
```

On my Activity I have placed this code:

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) { 
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == FirstInstallFragment.PICK_IMAGE_CALLBACK && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
        if (data.getData() == null) {
            return;
        }

        FirstInstallFragment firstInstallFragment = (FirstInstallFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(FIRST_INSTALL_FRAGMENT_TAG);
        if (firstInstallFragment != null && firstInstallFragment.isVisible())
        {
            firstInstallFragment.onOpenImageResult(data);
        } 
    } 
}
```

Now the weird thing is that, when I choose an image from image gallery my application closes but not in a way that it shutdown but like when you are in an activity and you press back button and it close but still run in background.

I have placed a breakpoint in `onActivityResult()` but it doesn't work, so I guess it doesn't go inside `onActivityResult()`.

Why is this happening and how can I show again the Fragment after picking an image?

Comment: why you are handling onActivityResult in Activity not in fragment?

Comment: I tried putting it in the fragment also, I had the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of calling `onActivityResult()` in activity call the same in fragment because you have used `startActivityForResult()` and not `getActivity().startActivityForResult()` so this is why you are not able to get callback in activity's `onActivityResult()`.

you can do this

```
 Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setType("image/*");
        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        getActivity().startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Picture"), PICK_IMAGE_CALLBACK);
```

or you can override this method in your fragment

```
@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }
```

When you call `startActivityForResult()`  the  `onActivityResult()` method of activity will get the response first after that `onActivityResult()` of Fragment will get triggered.

Comment: I tried both options and I still face the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that if you run this code on the Main activity of your app you will have this problem. I managed to solve it by implementing the code in an another activity.